# why pending jobs are cancelled after reboot?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

When adding the jobs in job scheduler and reboot the system. all pending jobs are cancelled. why? how to resolve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't set them as persisted.  When you build the JobInfo structure, remember to call setPersisted(true).  Otherwise it won't last around reboots.